# Do i need a passport in order to travel across the EU via Flixbus

Tags: schengen, common-travel-area

a relative living with me does not hold a EU passport because he is not a citizen, and moreover he has an expired passport of his origin country. He went to the consulate in order to renew it. We have to head in Belgium with FlixBys and come back in Italy, so is it possible for him to travel only with a receipt of passport renewal and Italian PR since there's no border control in EU and we'll be traveling via coach?

Comment: Even though there should be no systematic checks, you **must** have valid ID while travelling in the Schengen Area (and no, a PR card is not considered "valid ID"). Also, there are reports of some bus drivers checking IDs before boarding. Even though you might slip through (if no checks are made, or if whoever checks is fine with the PR card), you could get into trouble.

Comment: I've not said that PR card is a identity document, but if the renewal of the passports takes too much time and he has to travel in Belgium for a very important reason, isn'r it enough the RECEIPT of renewal?

Comment: I just had 2 passport checks today at borders travelling with Flixbus. It doesn't have anything to do with Flixbus - all vehicles are checked. But the driver didn't check my passport yet still it is required.